# Namespace for prefix 'xsi' has not been declared

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, namespaces

I'm new into java and xml parsing processes, so i got stucked. My xml is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<LauncherInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/edoc/2009/Launcher.xml" hash="d8bf41f6053ab2df28704dfcda443f9199546d3b">
  <File Name="parakstitais.edoc" Location="vieta_kur_saglabat" />
  <Action xsi:type="CreateNewSignAction">
    <FileReferences>
        <FileReference Name="Document1.doc" Address="some url" />
        <FileReference Name="Scan7.pdf" Address="some url" />
        <FileReference Name="Scan8.pdf" Address="some url" />
    </FileReferences>
  </Action>
</LauncherInfo>
```

and my goal is to extract all Action part, so it should be like:

```
<Action xsi:type="CreateNewSignAction">
    <FileReferences>
        <FileReference Name="Document1.doc" Address="some url" />
        <FileReference Name="Scan7.pdf" Address="some url" />
        <FileReference Name="Scan8.pdf" Address="some url" />
    </FileReferences>
  </Action>
```

Currently my Java code is

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException,
        MalformedURLException, SAXException, IOException,
        TransformerException, XPathExpressionException {

    String URL = "my xml URL";
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(false);

    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(new URL(URL).openStream());

     URL namespaceURL = new URL("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        String namespace = "xmlns:xsi="+namespaceURL.toString();

        Element messages = doc.createElementNS(namespace, "messages");
        doc.appendChild(messages);

    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();


    Node result = (Node) xPath.evaluate("LauncherInfo/Action", doc,
            XPathConstants.NODE);

    System.out.println(nodeToString(result));
    System.out.println("...");
}

private static String nodeToString(Node node) throws TransformerException {
    StringWriter buf = new StringWriter();
    Transformer xform = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    xform.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    xform.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(buf));
    return (buf.toString());
}
```

When launching an error appears: 
ERROR:  'Namespace for prefix 'xsi' has not been declared.'. 
I suppose that something with namespace declaration should be done. Is there any way to declare namepace URI in xpath query, or there is a better solution?

Comment: I'm not very much into Java, but it's likely that what you have to do is including `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` on the `Action` element of your output.

Answer (score 1):

the schema location of xsi need to be mentioned..
for example 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33693341/error-namespace-for-prefix-xsi-has-not-been-declared

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
    URL namespaceURL = new URL("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    String namespace = "xmlns:xsi="+namespaceURL.toString();

    Element messages = doc.createElementNS(namespace, "messages");
```

To:

```
    String namespaceURL = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    Element messages = doc.createElementNS(namespaceURL, "messages");
```

Reasons:

1. A namespace URI is not necessarily a URL; it's overkill to wrap it in a URL instance in Java and it may not always be valid. Just use a String to hold it.
2. The method `createElementNS` expects the namespace URI as-is; it doesn't expect a `xmlns:xi=` declaration in front of it. That declaration will be automatically generated by the XML serializer when you write out the DOM tree to a file or to a string.

Answer (score -1):

If you want all Action part extracted you should use a parser like this

```
string input = xmlFile;
string[] parts2 = Regex.Split(input, "(<action)|(</action>"));
```

And you will get an array of stings in each element is a action code.